# Using Tensorflow to optimize a function in python

Tags: python, tensorflow, optimization

I'm new to tensorflow and try to understand how to use outside of a machine learning context. I would like to optimize a python function with the ADAM implemenation of tensorflow.

Let's assume I have the following function:

```html
def fun_test(x):
    """
    :param x: List of parameters, e.g. [1,2,3]
    :return: real value
    """
    res=do_something(x)
    return res
```

When using scipy, I would call 'scipy.minimize(fun_test,x0,method="Nelder-Mead")'. How could I do this with tensorflow?

Best,
Michael

Answer (score 0):

You need to rewrite the function `do_something` to take tensors as inputs and returns a scalar tensor (i.e. creating a computation graph). Then the following code is a sketch of how to perform optimization on the function. (BTW, in your code `fun_test` and  `do_something` has no real difference so I picked the latter).

```
x = tf.get_variable("x", dtype=..., initializer=...)
target = do_something(x)
opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(...).minimize(target)  # Defines one optimization step
with tf.Session() as sess:
   sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())  # Initialize x

   NUM_STEPS = 1000
   for _ in range(NUM_STEPS):
      sess.run(opt)          # Run optimization for NUM_STEPS steps

   print(sess.run(x))        # Show values of x
   print(sess.run(target))   # Show target value
```